# Handling special characters in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, hash, character

I'm developing a Cocoa App in Swift, but I'm stuck trying to do something that must be easy to do but somehow I'm not getting the result I expect.

In my application, I'm trying to hash a word to MD5. Everything works fine when I skip special characters. When I try to hash a word with special characters, the resultant hash doesn't correspond to the correct hash.

Here's my code.

```
import Cocoa

let task = NSTask()
let pipe = NSPipe()
task.standardOutput = pipe

task.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
task.arguments = ["-c", "echo -n 'Canción' | md5"]

let file:NSFileHandle = pipe.fileHandleForReading
task.launch()
task.waitUntilExit()

let data =  file.readDataToEndOfFile()
let datastring = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String!
print("Hash = \(datastring)")
```

If you run this code in a Playground, you'll get this hash:

```
Hash = 770f92a03e9c82af426549941a9df70b
```

But, if you run the next command directly in your OS X terminal, you'll get the correct hash, which is Totally different to the first one.

```
$ echo -n 'Canción' | md5
```

This is the terminal response:

```
3abf536a5262c902a30d74f68f38067b
```

It is clear that I'm missing something important, but I can't find what's in my code.

Anyone?

Please... help!

Comment: Here's a clue:  The `ó` is the problem.  If you remove that character, you get the same results in both places.  Perhaps there is some setting for the character encoding that needs to be made.

Comment: If you change `md5` to `Od -x` you can see the hex codes that are being delivered to `Od` and likewise to `md5` and they are different.

Comment: That's interesting. Apparently, `NSTask` passes all argument strings in the "decomposed mapping", i.e. "ó" as "o" + "´". – This seems to be a "bug" in NSTask, also observed here: http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2005/Nov/msg00320.html.

Comment: Also observed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459711/how-to-work-around-nstask-calling-nsstring-filesystemrepresentation-for-argum, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533944/nstask-string-encoding-problem.

Comment: That's correct @vacawama The problem is the `ó` character. I need to read more about `Od`command line. It's not common for me to work with octals.  Thanx for the clue!

Comment: Hello @MartinR , I guess that's happening. `NSTask` is doing something weird to the string. It seems like you said: It is decomposing the string but I couldn't prove it. I'll let you know if I find something, guys. Thanx!

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am experiencing the same issues with german umlauts.